# How to persist MySQL container on Windows 10 between reboots

Tags: mysql, wordpress, windows, docker, containers

I'm using a native Docker for Windows (on Windows 10) for WordPress development. I have two containers: WordPress and MySQL. MySQL container has a data volume where DB data is stored between runs.

I start containers with 'docker-compose up -d' and stop with 'docker-compose down'. When stopped this way, MySQL data is saved properly to the data volume and when I start it next time I see all my changes persisted.

However, if I reboot Windows 10 without stopping MySQL containers first, it seems that changes made to the database since the last start are not saved. Docker for Windows is smart enough to start the same volumes that were running before reboot but does it really not care about shutting them down properly so the DB data be saved? Is it really so or do I misunderstand anything?

What is the most reliable way to avoid losing data on a system reboot? Stopping all MySQL container manually before reboot is a tedious task, especially when multiple servers are running. Probably I can create a script that will parse 'docker ps' output and will stop all the MySQL containers before reboot but I'm afraid I am probably reinventing a wheel here.

What's the best way to deal with a situation? I've searched high and low but found nothing on a topic. Am I the only one who needs this? Am I missing anything here?

Any help really appreciated! Thanks!

P.S. My docker-compose.yml file is:

```
version: '2'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
 ports:
  - "9013:3306"
 volumes:
   - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
 restart: always
 environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
   MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
   MYSQL_USER: wordpress
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
 depends_on:
   - db
 image: wordpress:latest
 volumes:
   - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
 ports:
   - "8013:80"
 restart: always
 environment:
   WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
   WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
   WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
   WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: wpd1_
```

Comment: Can you show your `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: @janshair-khan, added that to my question text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some additional investigation and I think the problem I asked about never existed. It was actually a Docker for Windows issue of a different kind: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/584.

Here is what was happening.
 1. When machine was rebooted, all persistent MySQL data was in fact saved correctly.
 2. But after computer restart Docker was not able to mount a volume because the volume became available a few seconds after container was autostarted (please see a comment here: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/584#issuecomment-286792858). As a result of this, MySQL database was empty (volume was not mounted, no data can be read).

If to restart a container manually, all persistent data will become loaded properly. So it was not the issue I thought of, but a different issue that is, luckily, a much less severe one.

Thanks to everyone trying to help me to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference) for your MySQL data.

```
volumes:
  - data-volume:/var/lib/db
```

(the destination should be where MySQL stores it's data)

Comment: That's what I am using: 
`
volumes:
   - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
`
It seems to be saving data to the volume only after I do 'docker-composer down'. But on Windows reboot Docker for Windows does not shut down containers in a way that 'docker-compose down' do, so the data is lost. Doing it manually now, but in case I forget before rebooting a machine bad things will happen. Looking for a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Windows file system access from the Docker-engine by right-clicking Docker Icon (At bottom-right corner) and mount shared Windows drives. If that's already done, you may need to provide full path to the drive i.e.

```
volumes:
  - c:\data:/var/lib/db
```

Also try removing `./` i.e. change to:

```
 volumes:
  - wordpress:/var/www/html
```

Comment: it seems that it does not work with specifying `wordpress:/var/www/html`. It has to be `./wordpress:/var/www/html` if it is a subfolder inside a directory with docker-compose.yml file.

It seems to be that this issue is related to https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/584 and not what I initially though it was (please see my answer above).

Thanks for helping me to solve this!